# Install InfluxDB without root access

Tags: influxdb

Is there a possibility to install [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/) without root access on Ubuntu 14.04?

There seem to be two ways of installing InfluXDB:

- From [binaries](http://influxdb.com/download/) (rpm, deb)
- Or [compile from sources](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/blob/master/docs/contributing.md)

Compiling from [sources](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb) is quite involving and requires number of packages being pre-installed.

I tried to install deb package without root access but failed at it so far. Is there a way to install InfluDB without root access on Ubuntu?

Comment: I've just got here with the same question. Are they silly? How limiting is that to require root access for running DB. In corporate environment no developer is even able to try it or prepare some prove of concept so he could charm business people and get required approvals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the tarball, extract it and find a binary file called 'influxd'.

1. Make it executable

   chmod +x influxd
2. Generate a config file

   ./influxd config > influxdb.conf
3. Start the service using

   ./influxd --config influxdb.conf
4. For testing, find another binary called 'influx' in the extracted folder and run

chmod +x influx

./influx

If it is started then it would say 'Connected to http://localhost:8086'. Otherwise there must be some port occupied.

Ports used in influxdb are - 8086 and 8088.

For more details or if you want to change the ports:

https://csetutorials.com/install-influxdb-without-root-access-linux.html

Comment: Can you include summary of required steps in the answer? I will be happy to accept this as an answer once included.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the binary tarball which you can find [on the download page](http://s3.amazonaws.com/influxdb/influxdb-latest.amd64.tar.gz). After extracting the content, you'll find the daemon, called `influxdb` in the root of the archive. You'll need to modify the config file `config.toml` to set the paths of the log file, data directory, etc. After that you should be able to run influxdb by just running `./influxdb` from the directory where you extracted the archive. If you have any further questions feel free to send your questions to the mailing list of contact us on irc (details can be found on [community page](http://influxdb.com/community/))

Comment: Thanks very much, I gave it a try and failed unfortunately. It would be great if influxdb can provide the binaries as well on top of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are few more options right now, see for details:
https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads

Specifically, you can find the Linux tarball binaries.